# How to set an alarm to exact hour on following days?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

I'm trying to make an alarm that besides shoot today, repeat on the exact same hour on the next day.

Not having any success until now.

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timeHOUR);
 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, timeHOUR);
 calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timeMINUTE);
```

The alarm must occur at the same times on the following days.

```
        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Also i need to be able to register more than 1 alarm. I'm not sure if **setRepeating()** supports that.

Comment: What does the Javadoc for `setRepeating` say? Also, `Calendar` is deprecated nowadays in favor of the `java.time` API.

Comment: It has no error output. I'm afraid calendar.getTimeInMillis() is adding up the total time for execution. Example: if I needed the alarm to go off at 4:15 pm it converts ((16 * 60) + 15) * 60 * 1000 to the first action. So it's not working. I'm not sure how the Alarm Manager works.

Comment: That's why I'm suggesting you look at the documentation for Alarm Manager.

Comment: Thankyou very much David!